# ASP.NET Core Web API - Queries performing 'LastOrDefault' operation must have a deterministic sort order

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API using Entity Framework, I have this code:

```
public async Task<Response<NotificationCredentialListDto>> CreateNotificationCredentialAsync(CreateNotificationCredentialDto requestDto)
{
    var userName = _currentUserService.UserName;
    var response = new Response<NotificationCredentialListDto>();
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        if (userName != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var notification = _mapper.Map<NotificationCredential>(requestDto);
                var existingNotification = _dbContext.NotificationCredentials.LastOrDefault(e => e.MerchantId == notification.MerchantId && e.IsModified == false);
                if (existingNotification != null)
                {
                    existingNotification.IsModified = true;
                    _unitOfWork.MerchantNotificationCredentials.Update(notification);
                    await _unitOfWork.Save();
                }
                requestDto.IsModified = false;
                notification.IsModified = requestDto.IsModified;
                notification.UserName = requestDto.UserName;
                requestDto.BasicAuth = encoded;
                notification.BasicAuth = requestDto.BasicAuth;
                notification.CreatedBy = _currentUserService.UserName;

                await _unitOfWork.MerchantNotificationCredentials.InsertAsync(notification);
                await _unitOfWork.Save();
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("An error occured: " + ex);
                transaction.Dispose();
                return response;
            }
        }
        _logger.Error("Registration failed");
        transaction.Dispose();
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        response.Successful = false;
        response.Message = "Registration failed. Please try again";
        return response;
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that if record exist, it should update the last record as:

```
IsModified = true
```

and also insert a new one.

But I git this error:

> An error occured: System.InvalidOperationException: Queries performing 'LastOrDefault' operation must have a deterministic sort order. Rewrite the query to apply an 'OrderBy' operation on the sequence before calling 'LastOrDefault'.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Last record based on what? You want the last inserted record?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos - Based on CreatedAt. It should check the table if record exists. Then if yes, it should update isModified = true in the last record in the table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i access an object in a list in c# query with ef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65516120/how-can-i-access-an-object-in-a-list-in-c-sharp-query-with-ef)

Comment: You need an `.OrderBy(e => e.CreatedAt)` before the `.LastOrDefault()`, in the second line of your `try` block (by the way, this is what the error message tells you to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [@Rafalon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7831383/rafalon) mentioned, you need to sort the collection using `OrderBy()` before using `LastOrDefault()`.

```
var existingNotification = _dbContext.NotificationCredentials.OrderBy(e => e.CreatedAt).LastOrDefault(e => e.MerchantId == notification.MerchantId && e.IsModified == false);
```

But be careful because multiple records could have been added before `CreateNotificationCredentialAsync` is called. Maybe you should search for all records where `MerchantId = notification.MerchantId` and `e.IsModified = false`:

```
var existingNotifications = _dbContext.NotificationCredentials.Where(e => e.MerchantId == notification.MerchantId && e.IsModified == false).ToList();
```

and update `IsModified` property to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think your code does not work correctly because after checking the condition `existingNotification != null` and updating the entity `MerchantNotificationCredentials` you are inserting it in next lines.

Second, I suggest change code to this:

```
public async Task<Response<NotificationCredentialListDto>> CreateNotificationCredentialAsync(CreateNotificationCredentialDto requestDto)
{
    var userName = _currentUserService.UserName;
    var response = new Response<NotificationCredentialListDto>();
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        if (userName != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var notification = _mapper.Map<NotificationCredential>(requestDto);
                var existingNotification = await _dbContext.NotificationCredentials.Where(e => e.MerchantId == notification.MerchantId && e.IsModified == false).OrderByDescending(x=>x.CreatedAt).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
               
                if (existingNotification != null)
                {
                    existingNotification.IsModified = true;
                    _unitOfWork.MerchantNotificationCredentials.Update(notification);
                    await _unitOfWork.Save();
                    return response;
                }
               
                requestDto.IsModified = false;
                notification.IsModified = requestDto.IsModified;
                notification.UserName = requestDto.UserName;
                requestDto.BasicAuth = encoded;
                notification.BasicAuth = requestDto.BasicAuth;
                notification.CreatedBy = _currentUserService.UserName;

                await _unitOfWork.MerchantNotificationCredentials.InsertAsync(notification);
                await _unitOfWork.Save();
          
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("An error occured: " + ex);
                transaction.Dispose();
                return response;
            }
        }
        _logger.Error("Registration failed");
        transaction.Dispose();
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        response.Successful = false;
        response.Message = "Registration failed. Please try again";
        return response;
    }
}
```